# Macro in `\section` names expand in context of `\nameref`

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, expansion

If I have a `\section` where its name includes a macro, if I try to reference that section via `\nameref` the included macro seems to be expanded at the point of the `\nameref` rather than the point of the `\section`.

I'm reasonably sure I know why the wrong thing is happening, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the right thing happen.

How do I make this work correctly? Is it possible to make this work correctly?

---

### Minimal example

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\begin{empty}
\newcommand{\foo}{Foo}
\section{\foo}...  %%%% Shows up as Foo (correct)
\label{XYZZY}

\paragraph{Good} \nameref{XYZZY}  %%%%% Gives Foo (correct)
\end{empty}

\begin{empty}
\newcommand{\foo}{Bar}
\paragraph{Bad} \nameref{XYZZY}   %%%%% Gives Bar (incorrect)
\end{empty}

% \paragraph{Ugly} \nameref{XYZZY}  %%% Gives "Undefined control sequence" error message.

\end{document}
```

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If not already loaded, then the package **nameref** loads the package **gettitlestring** which provides facilities for extracting the title of the section in question from a sectioning-command's arguments and making the title available to the command `\label` via the internal macro `\@currentlabelname`.
If **gettitlestring** is loaded with the option `expand` (which is not the default but which can be triggered, e.g., via `\PassOptionsToPackage`), then things get expanded by means of `\protected@edef` in the course of extracting the title and making it available to the command `\label` by (re)defining `\@currentlabelnane`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{expand}{gettitlestring}% Have title-phrases referenceable via \nameref expanded
                                             % by means of \protected@edef while preparing \@currentlabelname
                                             % which in turn is used by the command \label when writing
                                             % cross-referencing-data to the corresponding \newlabel-entry
                                             % in the aux-file.
\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\begin{empty}
\newcommand{\foo}{Foo}
\section{\foo}...  %%%% Gives Foo (correct)
\label{XYZZY}

\paragraph{Good} \nameref{XYZZY}  %%%%% Gives Foo (correct)
\end{empty}

\begin{empty}
\newcommand{\foo}{Bar}
\paragraph{Not bad} \nameref{XYZZY}   %%%%% Gives Foo (correct)
\end{empty}

\paragraph{Not ugly} \nameref{XYZZY}  %%% Gives Foo (correct)

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If **gettitlestring** is not loaded with the option `expand`, then the aux-file contains the following `\newlabel`-entry:
`\newlabel{XYZZY}{{1}{1}{\foo }{}{}}`
, where things are not expanded and thus get expanded at the time of cross-referencing the label via `\nameref`.

If **gettitlestring** is loaded with the option `expand`, then the aux-file contains the following `\newlabel`-entry:
`\newlabel{XYZZY}{{1}{1}{Foo}{}{}}`
, where things got expanded when **gettitlestring** prepared/provided the data for `\nameref`-referernces.

---

Some remarks about robustness/expansion of title strings can be found in [section 3 of the manual of the package nameref](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/nameref.pdf#page.4).

Comment: it should be noted that expand is not the default option, as it is slightly more fragile (nowadays much more commands are robust by default, so it doesn't matter so much anymore).

Comment: Thank! - Looks like in my case I can use `\usepackage[expand]{gettitlestring}` as long as I place it correctly.

Comment: @BCS Yes, you can. I prefer `\PassOptionsToPackage`:`\usepackage`-directives  might affect the order in time in which packages are loaded. `\PassOptionsToPackage`-directives do not trigger loading the package in question, thus they don't affect the order in time in which packages are loaded (one by another).  I think it is a matter of personal taste. Just do what you prefer and what you think suits your needs and requirements best.